# Error handling in sets of batch files running in Windows task scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, dos

Let's say I have 5 batch files that run sequentially one after another (executed via the Windows task scheduler on a normal Windows XP PC):

```
Script1.bat
Script2.bat
Script3.bat
Script4.bat
Script5.bat
```

Suppose one of the scripts fail (an error condition is detected -- details on how this happens is not important for my question here). How do I stop the other scripts from running if they all run within the task scheduler? For example, if Script1.bat fails, I don't want to run Script2-5.bat. If Script3.bat fails, I don't want to run Script4-5.bat, etc.

I thought about writing a flag value to a temporary file that each script would read from. At the beginning of each script (except for the first one), it will check to see if the flag is valid. The first script would clear out this flag at the beginning each time these set of batch files run.

Surely there is a better way to do this or maybe there is a standard for how to handle this type of situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a master.bat file that conditionally calls each of the scripts in sequence. Then schedule the master instead of directly scheduling the 5 scripts.

```
@echo off
call Script1.bat
if %errorlevel%==0 call Script2.bat
if %errorlevel%==0 call Script3.bat
if %errorlevel%==0 call Script4.bat
if %errorlevel%==0 call Script5.bat
```